# Why always get 5 spaces when nothing inside conteneditable div?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I get innerHTML in contenteditable div to a NSString like this:

```
NSString *htmlText = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('content').innerHTML"];
if (htmlText) {
    NSLog(@"TEST: |%@"|,htmlText);
}
```

I wanna check when nothing inside that div but I always get 5spaces when nothing inside div.
Why? Please help!

```
<div id="content" contenteditable="true" style="font-family: Helvetica">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the this code:

```
<div id="content" contenteditable="true" style="font-family: Helvetica">
</div>
```

May be there will be space after the

```
<div id="content" contenteditable="true" style="font-family: Helvetica"> << space will be there
```

So use this:

```
<div id="content" contenteditable="true" style="font-family: Helvetica"></div>
```

Do the closing of div after the starting div.

This will give right value in `innerHTML`.

Comment: Thanks! This work for the first time, but after I input text and delete all. I get <br> again. When user delete all text, I want to dynamic check string.length must equal 0. Can it?

Comment: @UFO Can you show more code ... from where you are inserting and deleting the text in this div.

Comment: I input text from keyboard when contenteditable="true". And check innerHTML by NSTimmer

Comment: @UFO Use the replace function of javascript. it will definitely work for you.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I can control some special case